# How to remove wordpress date archive pages?

Tags: wordpress

I have developed my own wordpress theme, and learning all kinds of programming stuff, but my priority is the content, not the programming knownledge. I need to know how to remove archive date listing from wordpress?

Question 1: The google search results displayed like this: virmodrosti.com/2017/05/
I don't want any kind of date archive option, how do you disable that?
I also don't use any kind of plugin, and always like to do it on my own.

Question 2: I don't know why older entries doesn't work anymore

virmodrosti.com/zdravje/ this page works fine

virmodrosti.com/zdravje/page/2/ it redirects to 404 error page

I only choose option in wordpress to hide that annoying /category/ with dash . inside editor at permanlinks, Category base. Maybe somehow these stuff is kinda fighting with each other and doesn't work properly.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi mate, you should do 1 post per question, keep that in mind for next time :)

*Question 1:* Have a look to the permalink under **Settings -> Permalinks**

Comment: I have custom structure /%category%/%postname%/ but would like to disable that since google contain virmodrosti.com/2017/05/ at search results. It means wordpress doesnt obey the commands, since date archive is still available

Comment: The older entries works, so I need to know how to remove wordpress date archive listing so that they wont appear in google search results.

Answer (score 1):

This is code from Digital Nomad theme I maintain:

```
function digitalnomad_remove_date_archives() {

    //if we are on date archive page
    if ( is_date() ) {
        // theme sets alternatine archive page with table like list of all posts
        $archive_page = get_option( 'digitalnomad_archive_page' );
        if ( $archive_page ) {
            // redirs to alternatine archive page if configured (good for SEO)
            wp_redirect( esc_url( get_page_link( $archive_page ) ) );
            die();
        } else {
            // otherwise error 404 is displayed
            global $wp_query;
            $wp_query->set_404();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'digitalnomad_remove_date_archives' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [smart Archive Page Remover wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-archive-page-remove/)
or visit your theme's `functions.php` file
then insert this code

```
/* Register template redirect action callback */
add_action('template_redirect','makes_remove_wp_archives');

/* Remove archive*/
function makes_remove_wp_archives(){
    // if we are on category or tag or date or author archive
    if(is_category()|| is_tag()||is_author()){
     global $wp_query;
     $wp_query->set_404();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed || is_date() in that one.
if(is_category()|| is_tag()|| is_date() ||is_author()){

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).